# Programmatically create issue in Mantis

Tags: node.js, soap, soap-client

I am writing small node.js script that will run multiple command & if any one fails, it will report an issue on the mentis. I am using following code to report issue in mantis bugtracker. Mantis bug tracker comes with an bunch of SOAP api to do stuffs like this. http://www.mantisbt.org/bugs/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl#op.idp90022480

```
var soap = require('soap');
  var url = 'http://localhost/mantisbt-1.2.19/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl';
  var user = 'administrator';
  var password = 'root';
  var args = {
        username: user, 
        password: password,         
        project: {
            id: 1
        },
        category: 'General',
        summary: 'Test summary', 
        description: 'test description'
    };  

  soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {

      client.mc_issue_add(args, function(err1, result) {
        if(err1)
            console.log( err1 );
        else
            console.log('Issue successfully created');
      });

  });
```

But I am getting following error log:

```
<faultstring>Project \'\' does not exist.</faultstring>
```

I have a project with id 1, & I can create an issue with same data using php.  My understanding is project id is not being send properly. Equivalent php code is as follow.

```
$c = new SoapClientDebug("http://localhost/mantisbt-1.2.19/api/soap/mantisconnect.php?wsdl", ['trace' => true]);

$username = 'administrator';
$password = 'root';
$issue = array ( 
    'summary' => 'PHP test issue', 
    'description' => 'PHP test description', 
    'project'=> array(      
        'id'=>1     
    ), 
    'category'=>'General',
);
$c->mc_issue_add($username, $password, $issue);
```

The php code is functional.

Answer (score 1):

Your args should be like this:

```
var args = {
    username: user, 
    password: password,
    issue: {         
      project: {
        id: 1
      },
      category: 'General',
      summary: 'Test summary', 
      description: 'test description'
    }
};
```